# VBA Word - How to store array or dict or coll while document is open

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am building a word document with content controls that will be used as a form. The dropdowns lists will come from a workbook and will be dynamically adjusted depending on the choices made.

Instead of re-accessing the workbook each time (and slowing things down), I am trying to store the necessary information in arrays and dictionaries to be used throughout the filling of the form at Document_Open(). I do not need (and don't want) the arrays/dict stored after the user closes the document.

I have tried declaring a Public dict outside of the function, no success (or maybe I am doing it wrong?). Can someone point me in the right direction.

thank you

```
Public dict As Object
Public Sub Document_Open()

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlWS As Object
    Dim cRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("O:\[..]\Library.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets(1)
    cRows = 21

        For i = 1 To cRows
            dict.Add xlWS.Range("C2").Cells(i, 1).Value, xlWS.Range("C2").Cells(i, 2).Value
        Next i

    Set xlWS = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

To be launched later

```
Sub test()

    Debug.Print dict("random key")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your public variable to a standard module (e.g. the module you sub `test` resides in) an everything will work fine.